# Difference between Security in Bluetooth low energy and BR/EDR

Tags: security, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

This is a basic questiion but I am not able to know it.. I have read the spec but still I am not clear.. My question is that In bluetooth low energy, we use Short term and long term keys in security. What are the differences between them? and also please tell me are these keys used in BR/EDR too? Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1):

Short Term Key (STK) is used as the first step for encryption (just after pairing is completed). Once a link is encrypted, Long Term Key ( LTK ) is then generated.

Basically, if master doesn't have an LTK generated against a slave, and the same slave attempts to connect again to master, the master assumes that the slave is not authenticated and hence attempts to pair again with the slave. If LTK is present, master understands that this device is already authenticated and proceeds for session encryption.

Answer (score 1):

To know the difference between the two, one should understand the phases of pairing in BLE:
Phase 1: two devices exchange device info such as capabilities etc.
Phase 2: the Short Term Key (STK) is generated based on defined procedure by BLE spec.
Phase 3: Long Term Key (LTK), Connection Signature Resolving Key (CSRK) and the Identity Resolving Key (IRK) are encrypted using STK and exchanged between the two devices.

After Phase 3,  STK won't be used any more. Instead, LTK is used for link layer encryption, while CSRK is used for AAT layer encryption depending on the security mode.

In short, STK is used during pairing to encrypt the LTK and other information between the devices, LTK is used afterwards in normal data transmission.

Comment: Actually the link is encrypted with the STK and then the keys are exchanged.

Answer (score 1):

It's too late but for the information of others.

**1.What is the difference between STK and LTK?**

From the [GUIDE TO BLE SECURITY](http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/Legacy/SP/nistspecialpublication800-121r1.pdf) :

> LE pairing begins with the two devices agreeing on a Temporary Key (TK), whose value depends on the pairing method being used. The devices then exchange random values and generate a Short Term Key (STK) based on these values and the TK. The link is then encrypted using the STK, which allows secure key distribution of the LTK, IRK and CSRK.

**2.Are these keys used in BR/EDR too?**

No, LTK and STK are not used in BR/EDR. The underlying pairing process is different in BR/EDR and BLE. BR/EDR uses key agreement while BLE uses key transport for pairing. In BR/EDR, link key is equivalent to LTK in BLE.